# How can i split a list of points in all angle

Tags: algorithm, draw

I try to seperate a list of point into all basic angle

[image]

Here's my code

```
var increment =15/50;       
var distance = 20;
var count = 0;

for( theta=0;theta <50; theta++) {      
  var newX = centerX +distance*Math.cos(theta*2*Math.PI*increment);
  var newY = centerY +distance*Math.sin(theta*2*Math.PI*increment);
  cxt.fillText("o",newX, newY);
  count++;
  if(count%5===0){
  distance=distance+20;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

I try to modify the increment many times but either they didn't make into straght lines or all the points turn into a mess
What is the exact increment number or function for this?

Comment: Note: your program would be simpler to understand, and much simpler to modify, if you were using two loops, one for the angle and one for the distance

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @MarcoZamboni splits given points into all basic angle as i said

Comment: But your code does not split given points, it just creates points at some angles and distances. Show reliable example of input data and desired result for that data

Comment: @MBo oh yes, that's my intention; place points at given angles

Comment: OK, and your code places points. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

No need for `count` - it is being incremented in exactly the same fashion as `theta`:

```
var increment =15/50;       
var distance = 20;

for( theta=0;theta <50; theta++) {      
  var newX = centerX +distance*Math.cos(theta*2*Math.PI*increment);
  var newY = centerY +distance*Math.sin(theta*2*Math.PI*increment);
  cxt.fillText("o",newX, newY);
  if(theta%5===0){  // just use theta here
    distance=distance+20;
  }
}
```

---

**Problem 2**

The `if` statement increments `distance` once every 5 points, which means each "ring" only contains 5 points, whereas they should have as many points as basic angles.  The logic should therefore be:

```
if (theta % 16 === 0) {  // there are 16 "basic angles"
  distance += 20;
}
```

---

**Problem 3**

`1` is not an integer multiple of the fractional increment `15/50`, so the second "ring" of points will not line up with the first - there will be an angular offset of `2*PI/5` between consecutive rings.

It is more efficient to separate the single loop into two nested loops, as suggested by `Damien`. The outer loop should increment the angle as the trigonometric functions are expensive.

```
var num_basic_angles = 16;  // number of basic angles
var separation = 20;        // distance between each point
var num_points;             // number of points per angle

for (var angle = 0; angle < num_basic_angles; angle++) {
  var theta = 2*Math.PI*angle/num_basic_angles;
  var cos_t = Math.cos(theta);
  var sin_t = Math.sin(theta);
  for (var point = 0; point < num_points; point++) {
    var x = centerX + distance * point * cos_t;
    var y = centerY + distance * point * sin_t;
    cxt.fillText("o",x,y);
  }
}
```

If you ***really*** want to do things in a single loop, use `theta = Math.floor(i / num_basic_angles), point = i % num_basic_angles`, where `i` is the loop counter from 0 to `num_basic_angles * num_points - 1`.

---

**Problem 4**

The "basic angles" are not evenly distributed, so incrementing by a fixed value will not work.

No need to be too smart here, because these basic angles are arbitrarily defined anyway. Just store them in an array:

```
var basic_angles = [0,30,45,60,90,120,135,150,180,210,224,240,270,300,315,330];

var separation = 20;  // distance between each point
var num_points;       // number of points per angle

for (var angle = 0; angle < basic_angles.length; angle++) {
  var theta = Math.PI/180.0*basic_angles[angle];
  var cos_t = Math.cos(theta);
  var sin_t = Math.sin(theta);
  for (var point = 0; point < num_points; point++) {
    var x = centerX + distance * point * cos_t;
    var y = centerY + distance * point * sin_t;
    cxt.fillText("o",x,y);
  }
}
```

Comment: may i ask if there're any way to implement this with just one loop? I try to make this by a list of points instead of define number of points per angle

Comment: @ToanNguyen you can use points from a single list by incrementing a counter in the inner loop and indexing the list with it; or you can use the approach I mentioned at the end of the `Problem 3` section